# Linux USB horror

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, usb

I've written a program, which creates a file on a mounted `USB` device. This can be done using a text based UI through an `RS232` connection. However, something seems to be off. 1 in 5 times, the whole process of writing to the `USB` device fails and I get the following:
[image]

Apparently an I/O error occurred and the kernel decided to unmount the device and detect it again. Any idea what the problem could be?
This error does not depend on the `USB` device in use, as I was able to reproduce this error using multiple different `USB` devices.

P.S.: I'm not sure if this question belongs on `stackoverflow`. If not, feel free to move it.

EDIT: The device in question is running Linux 2.6.24.6

EDIT:

I've just detected a very interesting behavior. I connected a USB stick to the device and created a tar of a large directory using the command:

```
tar -cvf test.tar ./test_directory
```

The directory is on an sd-card, i.e. on a completely different file system. However, while creating the archive, multiple USB disconnect & USB connect events occur:

```
--> start creating archive



/tmp # 
[74901.704258] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using fsl-ehci and address 18
[74901.914427] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[74902.020174] scsi18 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[74904.147779] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 18
[74904.573424] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using fsl-ehci and address 19
[74904.785303] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[74904.891860] scsi19 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[74907.748285] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 19
[74908.063438] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using fsl-ehci and address 20
[74908.264751] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[74908.311019] scsi20 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[74909.470917] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 20
[74909.783331] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using fsl-ehci and address 21
[74909.983410] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[74910.031500] scsi21 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[74915.106340] scsi 21:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[74915.184964] sd 21:0:0:0: [sda] 7884800 512-byte hardware sectors (4037 MB)
[74915.235993] sd 21:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[74915.275597] sd 21:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[74915.330972] sd 21:0:0:0: [sda] 7884800 512-byte hardware sectors (4037 MB)
[74915.379568] sd 21:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[74915.411428] sd 21:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[74915.457712]  sda: sda1
[74915.771348] sd 21:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[74915.805114] sd 21:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[74923.462332] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 21
[74924.484001] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using fsl-ehci and address 22
[74924.702678] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[74924.798064] scsi22 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[74929.855161] scsi 22:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[74929.951158] sd 22:0:0:0: [sda] 7884800 512-byte hardware sectors (4037 MB)
[74930.001646] sd 22:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[74930.034424] sd 22:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[74930.077218] sd 22:0:0:0: [sda] 7884800 512-byte hardware sectors (4037 MB)
[74930.131909] sd 22:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[74930.166881] sd 22:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[74930.208044]  sda: sda1
[74930.260520] sd 22:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[74930.303588] sd 22:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
[74931.951336] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 22
[74932.272609] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using fsl-ehci and address 23
[74932.483821] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[74932.569866] scsi23 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[74936.434380] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, address 23
[74936.754210] usb 2-1: new high speed USB device using fsl-ehci and address 24
[74937.751966] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[74937.820607] scsi24 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[74942.887336] scsi 24:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[74942.958666] sd 24:0:0:0: [sda] 7884800 512-byte hardware sectors (4037 MB)
[74943.004909] sd 24:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[74943.044027] sd 24:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[74943.101958] sd 24:0:0:0: [sda] 7884800 512-byte hardware sectors (4037 MB)
[74943.147503] sd 24:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[74943.190786] sd 24:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[74943.230368]  sda: sda1
[74943.258203] sd 24:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
[74943.314301] sd 24:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
```

I'm going to create a new thread for this question!

Comment: It is possible by any chance to update a kernel there?

Comment: @AndyShevchenko I've read somewhere that this particular kernel version can have issues with usb devices.  I'm not sure if we will be able to update it though

Comment: @AndyShevchenko updating the whole kernel won't be possible. But we can update some drivers.

Comment: I doubt you may update USB subsystem without updating kernel. Sorry, can't help in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apparently an I/O error occurred and the kernel decided to unmount the device and detect it again.

Its likely the other way around: The device is removed (by the USB subsystem) and causes errors because it was still mounted.

This looks like a hardware problem to me - AFAIK device detection and removal is done in hardware of the host controller or hub. Check cables and connections including soldered connections.

A look at the +5 Volts on the USB with an oscilloscope could be valuable, too - the voltage could be out of spec for a few ms, causing USB resets.

Comment: Correct. After investigating the layout on the board, I found that 2 wires were really close to each other. One of them connects to the USB port and the other to the SD card. So apparently crosstalk was occuring when writing to USB. After adding a ground plane between these wires, the issue got resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I/O error and directory bread messages are typical on corrupted file systems, and can usually be fixed with the fsck tool.
After fixing the file system, I would advise you to check that the connection was not interrupted in the middle of a write operation. Since your problem can be reproduced over several USB devices, I would check the RS232/USB interface first.

Comment: The issue occurs on 4 different USB devices. `fsck` says everything is clean. I even slow formatted a USB device (overwrite with zeroes), but to no avail.